How to properly dynamically load a webpack bundle created from Webpack 5 CacheGroups?
I have this webpack cacheGroup optimization:
optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    chunks: 'all', // Apply splitting to all types of chunks
                    minChunks: 2, // Minimum number of chunks that must share a module before splitting
                    maxAsyncRequests: 10, // Maximum number of parallel requests when loading asynchronously
                    maxInitialRequests: 10, // Maximum number of parallel requests at an entry point
                    cacheGroups: {
                        main: {
                            test: /[\\/]public[\\/]js[\\/](utils|middleware)[\\/]/,
                            name: 'main',
                            priority: 3,
                            enforce: true,
                            reuseExistingChunk: true
                        },

                    }
                },
              
            }

The output path for this writes to public/dist/main.bundle.js.
What I want to be able to do is at a particular point in my app when a reload happens I want to be able to dynamically load in this bundle. The bundle paths are written to a webpack_paths json file and I am trying something like this:
const webpackPaths = require('../dist/webpack_paths.json');

const loadBundle = async (bundleName) => {
    const bundlePath = webpackPaths[bundleName]; //Points to the path public/dist/main.bundle.js

    if (!bundlePath) {
        throw new Error(`Bundle path for ${bundleName} not found in webpack paths json file.`);
    }

    try {
        const imported = await import(/* webpackFetchPriority: "high" */ bundlePath);

        return imported;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to import bundle: ${bundleName} from path: ${bundlePath}`, error);
        throw error;
    }
};

const loadMainBundle = () => loadBundle('main.js'); // Resolves to correct path in json file.

export {
    loadMainBundle,
};


It always results in an error even though the file exists at this exact path in my repo:
code
: 
"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"
message
: 
"Cannot find module '/public/dist/main.bundle.js'"

What is the correct way to dynamically load in my webpack bundle so I can load it on demand where I need it?
